# How to inject ng-bind in head

Tags: angularjs

I need to use somo code I recibe from a rest web service in the head of my AngularJS aplication.

I try to storage the code in a rootscope variable like

```
$scope.head = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />';
```

And try to use it in the head like this

```
<ng-bind-html="head">
```

but don't work. If I do it in other place in htnl it works, but not in the head (I supousse angular is not yet load) How can I achieve it?

https://plnkr.co/edit/ilbNlCB0ibDs9LUuHiyX

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

I create a funtion in JS

```
$scope.updateHead = function(src){
        document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', src);
    }
```

and call to it

```
$scope.updateHead($scope.head);
```

I update the plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/ilbNlCB0ibDs9LUuHiyX